# CSS - Label & checkbox not aligning same as other labels and checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label, alignment

I'm making a small survey and my "checkbox-label" & checkboxes will not align the same as the other labels.
All the labels have the same class. I need it to align the same as the others.

Here is a link to my codepen to show you what I mean:

https://codepen.io/Saharalara/pen/xMGqPa

```css
.labels {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.rightTab {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 48%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.radio,
.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  left: -44px;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rowTab">
  <div class="labels">
    <label id="checkbox-label" for="changes">What do you think we should do to improve our fabulous toilet if any...</br>there should'nt be any but choose please:</label>
  </div>
  <div class "rightTab">
    <ul id="changes">
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="1" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Cleanliness</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input  name="prefer" value="2" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Friendliness</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input  name="prefer" value="3" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Everything, it's shite</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input  name="prefer" value="4" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Nothing, it's fantastic</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input  name="prefer" value="5" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">No changes required, it's is the best toilet I've ever been to</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a `=`. And, in this case, it's quite important. Change

```
<div class "rightTab">
```

... to:

```
<div class="rightTab">
```

See it [working here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NoNzed).

Comment: I can't believe it was just that. Thank you so much.  I spent so long reading this code over and over. Thanks again!!

Comment: That's an easy one. Detecting a space character at the end of a `php` file, creating a white screen of death. That used to be **the** challenge :). Have a great evening.